# Redirect Facebook News Feed page to Bookmarks/Lists page from any page on Facebook with Greasemonkey while onclick event triggered

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey

I want to redirect Facebook news feed page (example: https://www.facebook.com/) to this page: https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists only on my browser with Greasemonkey add-on. 
I wrote these till now:

```
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name        News Feed
    // @namespace   https://example.com/example
    // @description Redirecting News Feed
    // @include     https://web.facebook.com/*
    // @include     https://www.facebook.com/*
    // @version     1
    // @grant       none
    // @noframes
    // @run-at document-start
    // ==/UserScript==

    "use strict";

    if(window.location.href.slice(-4) == 'com/') {
        window.location = "https://web.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists";
    }

    document.onclick = function(event) {
      if(window.location.href.slice(-4) == 'com/') {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = "https://web.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists";
      }
    }
```

It is not working while onclick event triggered from a page on Facebook. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add console.log inside the onclick handler and see what happens.

Comment: console.log before the if statement is working, but not inside.

Comment: I meant use console.log to show some useful info: `console.log(location.href)`. From what I see this condition will never be satisfied because on 'com/` you redirect the page, so that the browser loads a new page with a new `document`, and your userscript is reinjected.